# Sort csv out put file in desending by Mailbox size with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sort-object

i have a script which is working without any problem, my only issue is that i can't order the output as i needed.

I've tried to remove the Sort-object CmdLet but it didn't change any thing, also I've tried to "play" with diffrient of variation of the Sort-object CmdLet.

here is the code:

```
  $users = Import-Csv "C:\CSV Test\Alias_test.csv"

  foreach ($user in $users) {

  Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $user.UserName |

   Select-Object @{l="User Name";e="DisplayName"},

   @{l="Mail Box Size";e="TotalItemSize"}, 

   @{l="TotalEmails?";e="itemcount"} |

   Sort-Object -Property ItemCount|

   Export-Csv "C:\CSV Test\Mailboxe_size.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation

                             } #end of ForEach loop
```

The csv file looks like that:

[image: Wrong order]

Thanks alot for your help

Comment: You should move the `Sort-Object` and `Export-CSV` part outside of the foreach loop.  ... this way it should be a little faster and you sort all objects, not each individual.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, i need to use the same format just after the last "}",
you mean like that : `} # end of foreach loop
Sort-Object -Property ItemCount|

   Export-Csv "C:\CSV Test\Mailboxe_size.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your current script.

First is that each users mailbox statistics are sorted individually, so move the `Sort-Object` statement outside of the loop.

Second problem is that by the time you sort the objects, the `ItemCount` property no longer exists, since you've renamed it to `TotalEmails?`, so make sure you update the `Property` argument:

```
$users = Import-Csv "C:\CSV Test\Alias_test.csv"

$stats = foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $user.UserName |
    Select-Object @{l="User Name";e="DisplayName"},
    @{l="Mail Box Size";e="TotalItemSize"}, 
    @{l="TotalEmails?";e="itemcount"} 
} #end of ForEach loop

$Stats |Sort-Object -Property TotalEmails? |Export-Csv "C:\CSV Test\Mailboxe_size.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help 
why did you use "?" after the "TotlaEmails" ?

i guess that by mistake?

Comment: I'm curious how the calculated property with a string expression could generate the pictured output.

Comment: @WebsGhost Because you used `TotalEmails?` in your original post, so I guess the real question is why did YOU use `?` after `TotalEmails` :D

Comment: @LotPings String expressions in calculated properties expand to dereference named properties, OPs output is "working as designed". Try `"Hello World?" |Select @{Name='NumberOfChars';Expression='Length'}` for yourself

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen Oh your right loool thanks, didn't noticed that i've used the "?"

Working like a charm !!! 
Thanks alot !

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, learned something new to me. The question title asks for ordering by Mailbox Size, is the ?string? TotalItemSize numerically sortable without first isolating the byte value?

Comment: @LotPings I don't have access to an Exchange lab atm, but assuming memory doesn't betray me, yes [ByteQuantifiedSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.bytequantifiedsize(v=exchg.150).aspx) values are sortable :)